# jqxhr keeps repeating with previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Hi I am a novice programmer so please be kind.

I have a page with a button on to submit a bid.

When I click this button it is sent to my server to check if i have enough funds to continue.

If its `true` its returned and the relevant modal is shown, `false` and a different modal is shown.

This works as you would expect, but if i then re-submit my bid (which may be `false`) the code appears to run **twice** when i watch it with breakpoints.

If I run it a 3rd time it appears to run 3 times etc. This would be fine as from the frontend you don't really notice it, but if my server returns true i get all of the false conditions running first then the true condition will run. 
This produces incorrect modals to the user.

So it looks like my code increments with the previous values before finally completing.

I hope this makes sense!

```
$("#goAheadAndPay").on('click',function(e) {
    $('#biddingModal').modal('hide');
    placeBid(builderid, jobid, bidAmount, currentNoOfBids);
});

function placeBid(builderid, jobid, bidAmount, currentNoOfBids) {
    var jqxhr = $.get( "/builder/placebid/" + builderid + "/" + jobid + "/" + bidAmount, function() {

    }).done(function(result) {
        displayModals(jqxhr.responseText, currentNoOfBids);
        // console.log(result);
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('Failed for some reason'); 
    }).always(function() {

    });
}

function displayModals(option, currentNoOfBids)
{
    if(option === 'false')
    {
        $('#biddingModalUnsuccess').modal();
    } 
    else if(option === 'true')
    {
        $('#biddingModalSuccess').modal();
    }            
}
```

Comment: Why do you treat `option` as _String_ and not _Boolean_?

Comment: try to remove the click event before listening to it. it might be added multiple times by other part off your code.

$("#goAheadAndPay").off('click').on('click',function(e) {

Comment: Thanks musicvicious that worked a treat :) Thank you again for your fast reply much appreciated.